How can I connect python to a database using sqlalchemy?
I am trying to create the connection to a database named etl_project but for some reason I keep getting a module not found error

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
last) Input In [61], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://server/etl_project')
File :2, in create_engine(url, **kwargs)
File
c:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py:281,
in deprecated_params..decorate..warned(fn, *args,
**kwargs)
274     if m in kwargs:
275         _warn_with_version(
276             messages[m],
277             versions[m],
278             version_warnings[m],
279             stacklevel=3,
280         )
--> 281 return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File
c:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py:599,
in create_engine(url, **kwargs)
597         if k in kwargs:
598             dbapi_args[k] = pop_kwarg(k)
--> 599     dbapi = dbapi_meth(**dbapi_args)
601 dialect_args["dbapi"] = dbapi
603 dialect_args.setdefault("compiler_linting", compiler.NO_LINTING)
File
c:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\connectors\pyodbc.py:60,
in PyODBCConnector.import_dbapi(cls)
58 @classmethod
59 def import_dbapi(cls) -> ModuleType:
---> 60     return import("pyodbc")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://server/etl_project')


I think your virtual environment is missing the pyodbc module. Try installing it with the following command:
pip install pyodbc


I had already installed that. its been sorted already. Thank you for your assistance
